# mysql , after a deletion, last inserted row sits just in the place of the deleted one

Tags: php, mysql

I am not going to  paste the code here and hope the statement of the prob is enough to pose the question .

i inserted 3 rows in a mysql table, deleted the 2nd one and then inserted the 4th one and all these things i did by writing code in php. but the 4th one sits in the place of the deleted one. That is I wanted  the order of the ids(primary key) to be 1,3,4. but now it becomes 1,4,3.

Thanks in advance for any solution.

Istiaque Ahmed
Bangladesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the table storage engine to [InnoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InnoDB).

[MyISAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyISAM)
and [InnoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_MySQL_database_engines#Comparison_between_InnoDB_and_MyISAM)

Comment: really this is very easy to implement and accomplish the puporse. thanks so many

Answer (score 2):

if you dont specify the sort order in your query then the db can return the rows in any order, so specify the sort order and all will be well